# How to mimic proximity to a bluetooth beacon through an Emulator

Tags: bluetooth, android-emulator, root, beacon, xposed

I want to use an emulator to "pretend" to be in the presence of a beacon given a UUID, major and minor.

I understand that emulators themselves don't directly support Bluetooth but is there any way to inject a Bluetooth device into the list of devices the emulator sees?

Does there exist an Xposed Module or some sort of root that can adhere to this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Standard Android emulators provide no way to simulate Bluetooth detections, so this is not possible at an Android API level.

If you use the open source [Android Beacon Library](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/), however, it does provide a `BeaconSimulator` (See [here](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/simulator/BeaconSimulator.java) ) Interface so you can inject beacon detections when using an Android Emulator.

To do this, simply create a new class that implements this interface, construct an instance and then register it like this:  `BeaconManager.setBeaconSimulator(myBeaconSumulator)`

After doing this, your app will detect any beacons in the list returned by your myBeaconSimulator object’s `getBeacons()` method when your app is running in debug mode on both Android Emulators and physical Android devices.

Comment: Would there be any way to do this through a different app (ran on the same emulator) ?

Comment: No, this solution requires a change to your app.  The Android Beacon Library code becomes part of your app once included.